# Personal liability insurance with no car or house

Tags: united-states, insurance

Is it possible to get a personal liability insurance if I don't drive (I don't have a driving license and I don't own a car) and if I don't own a house (I am renting)?

The use case I'm thinking about is if somebody gets hurt by my bike, if I inadvertently hurt someone while snowboarding, etc...

I cannot find any way to get any such insurance.

Comment: Aren't you just describing renters insurance? It's like homeowners but it doesn't cover the building.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling New York

Comment: how do you not have renters' insurance?

Answer (score 6):

Check with your insurance agent for a personal liability coverage addition to your renters' insurance, life insurance, travel insurance, or any other insurance product that you might have. You can also add umbrella insurance - on top of the liability coverage of a specific policy (home/auto/renters).

If you don't have any insurance policy at all, then why you're thinking of only these events? You should probably have a long talk with a reliable insurance agent about what coverages you need. Usually, if you're renting - you have to have some kind of renters' insurance.

Answer (score 0):

Why?  Personal Liability insurance is normally only needed if:

1. You have a target on your back; sizable assets that someone would want to go after

   AND (sometimes OR)
2. You perform some routine work (tree trimming service, etc.) that could cause damage or injury

You haven't listed any assets, and if "bike" means "motorcycle", then most if not all states require a minimum level of liability insurance in order to register/tag it anyway.